# Getting org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException in JBoss Fuse

Tags: jaxb, apache-camel, type-conversion, marshalling, jbossfuse

I'm getting the error below in JBoss Fuse.

Can someone tell me what's the reason that's causing this issue?

And is there a way to resolve it?

```
    java.io.IOException: org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type: com.abc.ws.ABC to the required type: java.io.InputStream with value com.abc.ws.ABC@7644b2af  at org.apache.camel.converter.jaxb.JaxbDataFormat.marshal(JaxbDataFormat.java:153) :

    <dataFormats>
    <jaxb contextPath="generated" id="generated"/>
    <jaxb contextPath="com.abc.ws" encoding="UTF-8" id="ABC"
    partClass="com.abc.ws.ABC" prettyPrint="true"/>
    </dataFormats>

    <route autoStartup="true" id="LogCreateOrgRequest">
    <from id="_from10" uri="seda:logOrganisationRequest"/>
    <process id="_process17" ref="AbcProcessor"/>
    <marshal id="_marshal1" ref="ABC"/>
    <convertBodyTo id="_convertBodyTo2" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <setBody id="_setBody18">
    <simple> Request - [${date:now:yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS.Z}]\nTransactionID 
    - ${exchangeProperty.CAFNo}\n${body}\n</simple>
    </setBody>
    <to id="_to40" pattern="InOut" uri="file:/opt/logs/demographicSetup/ABC?
 keepLastModified=true&amp;fileExist=Append&amp;fileName=CreateOrgRequest-${date:now:yyyyMMdd}.txt&amp;readLock=changed"/>
    </route>`
```

Comment: Complete Error : java.io.IOException: org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type: com.abc.ws.ABC to the required type: java.io.InputStream with value com.abc.ws.ABC@7644b2af  at org.apache.camel.converter.jaxb.JaxbDataFormat.marshal(JaxbDataFormat.java:153) : [268:org.apache.camel.camel-jaxb:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
 at org.apache.camel.processor.MarshalProcessor.process(MarshalProcessor.java:69)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
 at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(Instru

Comment: Seems, file component expecting input stream and your code sending object to it. Convert ABC object to stream before invoking file component.